# f-strings with variable in format specifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Can you create a f-string where you use a integer variable for the digits of padding?

```
>>> s = 8
>>> f"{'test':s}"
```

With `.format()` you could solve this doing something like:

```
>>> "{{:{}}}".format(s).format("test")
```

I'd use it for printing a list of names, padded by max name length:

```
s = max(map(len, names))
for n in names:
    print(f"The age of {n:s} is {ages[n]}.")
```

Comment: `n, s = "test", 8; f'{n:{s}}'` -> `'test    '`

Comment: Also, you don't have to use multiple calls to `str.format` to do the same with it: `"{:{}}".format(n, s)`

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable format specifier in curly brackets:

```
>>> s = 8
>>> f"{'test':s}"
'test'
>>> f"{'test':{s}}"
'test    '
```